# Where, outside of $HOME if anywhere, might account specific configs be found?

Tags: configuration, home, accounts

I have a most bamboozling problem.

I had a Mint 18 machine with Eclipse Neon. All worked fine.

I upgraded to Mint 19 and Eclipse Photon. Suddenly Eclipse is unusable.

The exact issue is documented here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536756

but the exact nature of the problem is digression from this question. What brings me here is this observation: I create a new user account, and in that account Eclipse Photon works fine.

OK, the pragmatist in me would just run with the new account now, time to clean up lint anyhow, my home folder is full of it I guess.

But the idealist in me wishes to understand why it is so, so I embarked on a quick test of sorts. In summary, I copied all $HOME/.* files and directories from my old account to the new, logged out and in again, and checked to see if Eclipse had the problem.  It doesn't!

Conclusion: there is no config in my $HOME/.* files or directories that is causing Eclipse to misbehave.

Which brings me to the question I have here. Where else may I look? Where else outside of $HOME/.* might account specific configs reside?

I am suspicious of dconf and gsettings (don't understand them well enough) and wonder fi they store all account specific confs under $HOME or elsewhere, and likewise if there are any other places account specific confs may reside?

I may try a full disk find and grep for the old account name to see if I can root out any references. That will be time consuming and slow and no 100% conclusive either.

So I am curious if there are known places I can concentrate the search.

Something is different between these two accounts that appears no to be in $HOME/.*.

Another strategy might be to backup $HOME then piece by piece simply remove things paring it down to a clean home folder if need be to see if the problem disappears and when. But taht's a fair bit of work and I would appreciate any insights into likely locations outside of $HOME that might store account specific configs, lest I spend ages barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: There’s something else different between the accounts: the usernames... Perhaps the configuration, wherever it is stored, is tied to the username. Note that in most Unix-like systems, the only place programs run by end users can expect to store data persistently is inside the user’s home directory; I’d be rather surprised if Eclipse had settings outside of `~/.eclipse`, related directories, and the individual project directories.

Comment: Does Eclipse have anything in `~/.config/`? Some systems set that as global config file location via XDG and programs that honour that put their stuff there.

Comment: I'd be inclined to try `strace` with logging to file, and then compare what files it's opening.

Comment: While not an answer to my question, I found the culprit was in $HOME! It seems human error led me to the conclusion it was not. But I attacked it far more rigorously and robustly and nailed the offending file. It is documented here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536756

The original question is thus not needing an answer any more. But hey, I guess it's still a valid question and interesting so I'll leave it for now. A valid answer might be: nowhere.